# Display animated gif after clicking link to go to a slow loading third party webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

My site links to a paypal buy it now page that loads slowly.  I would like to display an animated gif after the user clicks the paypal embeded link until the new paypal page loads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you loading the PayPal page?  Is it in a new window or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you tagged the question with jQuery, which is a great way to do it like Kerry suggested.

With jQuery this is really simple:

```
$("#paypalLink").click(function(){
      $(".loading").show();
}
```

And your html would look like this

```
<a href="http://paypal.com/whateverelse" id="paypalLink">Pay with Paypal</a>
<img src="loading.gif" class="loading" />
```

You'd hide the  "loading" class in your css when it the page loads( perhaps with display:none;), then show it with the jquery.

There are a number of ways that you can do this, just take this as a starting point.

For the jQuery click api go here => http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: How are you loading the paypal page? You'd have to load it in an iframe (which I don't think paypal would allow - I'd check) to stay on the same page.  Otherwise, once the user clicks the link it will go to Paypal while loading and you wouldn't have control over their site, of course.

Comment: @JohnKratz +1 , jquery rocks , i think the problem of "waiting" is because of slow dns ? .. on the side note : google provide fast dns. 8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript so that the "onclick" event either replaces the image or adds on a new image. I suggest using jQuery's either `.replaceWith('<img ...')` or `.append('<img ...')`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this without JQuery...

Let's assume you have the animated image on your page hidden with CSS (display:none;)

Then on your link you would do:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('loaderimage').style.display='';">Click Here</a>

<img src="loading.gif" id="loaderimage" alt="" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: @Sherri... i tried your code for mobile web application, its working iOS safari browser, but when i tried default android browser its not working, if try mobile chrome browser its work fine, any solution for work it default android web browser also.??? and even chrome or iOs safari or desktop browser when we click the link loading image working but when we press back button or comeback previous page this animated gif file still working there... how to hide it when we comeback to previous page.??  thanks..